# CSS element getting dimension of itself base on content

Tags: css

I know that this is something we would use JavaScript for, but I was wondering if it's possible or planned in next releases of CSS maybe.

I'm working on a little platform and there's a lot of relative/absolute positions. Content is dynamic so it's not a best solution to specify the static width and elements must be centered somehow. I made it possible with almost no display-errors using CSS only, but it would be great if there is something like `this` in css.

Today's code (SASS):

```
element 
    position: absolute
    top: 100px
    right: 50%
    margin-right: -50px (static width in %/px/em/rem/...)
```

Something I was thinking about:

```
element
    position: absolute
    top: 100px
    right: calc(50% - this.width / 2)
```

So, to not make this question too broad. Do you know some way to implement this kind of behavior in today's CSS? And if not, do you know if there are some plans to implement it in feature releases?

Comment: What should this even refer to in that example? The element itself? Makes no sense, because you can not involve the element in its own width calculation that way.

Comment: did you try with css variables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables ?

Comment: _"and there's a lot of relative/absolute positions"_ - sounds like that might rather be the real issue. Especially absolute positioning is something that one should use rather sparely, and not base the whole layout on. Exceptions of course exist; but will be rather inflexible most of the time. And quite frankly, most often you see that method of layouting used by people who haven't learned how to use CSS properly yet ...

Comment: I meant something like a possibilty for element to calculate it's own width if it's not specified (based on it's content width)

Comment: Does `right: calc(50% - this.width / 2)` mean you want to center it?

Comment: yes, well not now obviously as it wouldn't work. I was just wondering if there is something similar planned. As now when I want to center some element with absolute positioning (not flex-box) I need to know specific width/height of the element. It would be nice if there is something that would let the element calculate the dimensions of itself so we would be able to use that calculations in other styles

Comment: But you can center dynamically sized absolute positioned div's already, if that is what you want? ... I can post an answer how to

Comment: That's not a meaning of this question, but yes I would appreciate if you can maybe send me some link so I can take a look on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible today, to reference a property of it self.

Will it come? .. Hope so

In your particular sample, centering an absolute positioned div that has dynamic content, you can use `transform: translate`

*Side note: CSS has a lot of properties, where, when combined, one can still achieve similar effect, as with below sample*

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div>Centered with dynamic content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @LGSon. I did not think about the transform when I was centering it, really useful trick. I guess I can mark the answer as correct as it is correctly answering the "core" of my question.